# Node.js and mongodb access mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, windows-8

I'm trying to set up mongodb on Windows 8 using node.js, Does anyone know why im getting this error. C:\users\phill\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongodb\mongo_client.js:359  it also says at collection = db collection,,, can't call method 'collection' of null. I'm having a hard time setting it up. My goal is to be able to add to mongo db, and see that I add or pull up what I added, but adding something is good enough for me for now. I'm trying every thing I can find, even straight from the website, I tried everything I see on here as well. Think it maybe it's the way I have things set up. My node.js is saved in my c: drive there is a file that says, program files(86x) in there I have node_modules, npm and such. The path ends up being, computer > windows (C:) > program files(86x) > nodejs. My Mongodb is saved right on my C: drive the path end up being windows (C:) >  mongodb-win32-x86_64-2008plus-2.4.8. In my C: I also created a file data and in it created another db. I have been told i should just use mongoose, I'm just learning so i open to any advice, links or anything that will help. I have one last question as well, i learned php and then found out about sql injections and stuff like that, i am not seeing anything about security at all, should i expect the same as well. For this i get text not defined, but i have been getting errors with everthing i have done, best i did was get stuck on a right concern screen.

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/integration_test", function(err, db) {
test.equal(null, err);
test.ok(db != null);

db.collection("replicaset_mongo_client_collection").update({a:1},          
{b:1},  {upsert:true},          function(err, result) {
test.equal(null, err);
test.equal(1, result);

db.close();
test.done();
});
});
```

Tried this as well and getting a error,C:\users\phill\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongodb\mongo_client.js:359.... at collection = db collection,,, can't call method 'collection' of null. im calling it in command prompt node filename.js I'm saving it where my node.js file is, I have pulled up files before and created a server.

```
var Db = require('mongodb').Db,
MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient,
Server = require('mongodb').Server,
ReplSetServers = require('mongodb').ReplSetServers,
ObjectID = require('mongodb').ObjectID,
Binary = require('mongodb').Binary,
GridStore = require('mongodb').GridStore,
Grid = require('mongodb').Grid,
Code = require('mongodb').Code,
BSON = require('mongodb').pure().BSON,
assert = require('assert');

var db = new Db('test', new Server('localhost', 27017));
// Fetch a collection to insert document into
db.open(function(err, db) {
var collection = db.collection("simple_document_insert_collection_no_safe");
// Insert a single document
collection.insert({hello:'world_no_safe'});

// Wait for a second before finishing up, to ensure we have written the item to disk
setTimeout(function() {

// Fetch the document
collection.findOne({hello:'world_no_safe'}, function(err, item) {
assert.equal(null, err);
assert.equal('world_no_safe', item.hello);
db.close();
})
}, 100);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your first code example, you said:

> For this i get text not defined

I assume you meant "*test* not defined?" Your script only requires the `mongodb` library, and I don't believe `test` is a core nodejs function, so that would explain the error.

To reference the driver documentation for [db.collection()](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/db.html#collection), an `assert` library is used, but also properly imported (as you did in your second example).

Within your callback to `db.open()`, you don't check if an error occurred. That might shed some light on why `db` is null in that function.

Regarding your question about the equivalent of SQL injection with MongoDB, the main areas of concern are places where you might pass untrusted input into evaluated JavaScript, or using such input to construct free-form query objects (not simply using a string, but more like dropping an object into your BSON query). Both of these links should provide more information on the subject:

- [What type of attacks can be used vs MongoDB?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/23734/what-type-of-attacks-can-be-used-vs-mongodb)
- [How does MongoDB address SQL or Query injection?](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/developers/#how-does-mongodb-address-sql-or-query-injection)

Comment: thanks, kind of got it working through express. Still have not looked at security yet, but will defendant read your links! TY!